# Unable to reverse proxy requests to Nifi running in the backend using client cert as auth mechanism

Tags: nginx, apache-nifi

I have configured Nginx as reverse proxy server for my Nifi Application running in the backend on port 9443;

**

- Here goes my Nginx conf:

**

worker_processes 1;

events { worker_connections 1024; }

```
map_hash_bucket_size 128;
sendfile on;
large_client_header_buffers 4 64k;

upstream nifi {
server cloud-analytics-test2-nifi-a.insights.io:9443;
}



server {
listen 443 ssl;
#ssl on;
server_name nifi-test-nginx.insights.io;
ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/cert1.pem;
ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/privkey1.pem;

ssl_client_certificate /etc/nginx/nifi-client.pem; (this contains server cert and ca cert)
ssl_verify_client on;
ssl_verify_depth 2;

error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log debug;

proxy_ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/cert1.pem;
proxy_ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/privkey1.pem;
proxy_ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/nginx/nifi-client.pem;

location / {
proxy_pass https://nifi;
proxy_set_header X-ProxyScheme https;
proxy_set_header X-ProxyHost nifi-test-nginx.insights.io;
proxy_set_header X-ProxyPort 443;
proxy_set_header X-ProxyContextPath /;
proxy_set_header X-ProxiedEntitiesChain "<$ssl_client_s_dn>";
proxy_set_header X-SSL-CERT $ssl_client_escaped_cert;
}
}

}
```

When ever I try to access Nifi using Nginx Reverse Proxy Address/hostname I am getting below error.

**client SSL certificate verify error: (2:unable to get issuer certificate) while reading client request headers,**

Comment: Is it a self-signed certificate ?

Comment: its not self signed cert; I generated cert using ZeroSSL CA.

Comment: Ok i see so that maybe means that for some reason nginx is not able to get all the certificate chain, check on that machine if the CA which issued your certificate along with all the intermdiary ones are present on your truststore